# how up asp.net to host somee.com. contain devexpress

Tags: asp.net

I need up project to host somee.

but when up host somee.com don't access devexpress.

Error when log 1 page of project.
Parser Error Message: **Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

```
Line 20:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
Line 21:       <assemblies>
Line 22:         <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
Line 23:         <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v12.2, Version=12.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
Line 24:         <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
```

i want to know how to add devexpress into project to up hosting somee.com.

Thank you for readed

Comment: Did you put those assemblies (DevExpress.Web.v12.2 and DevExpress.Data.v12.2) in the bin folder of your project?

Comment: Why i use 3 layout. Project error same error I post. I add library of devexpress into File BIN.